# Не работает vertical align

Tags: html, css

Хочу выровнять элемент с классом btn-container по низу, элемент блочно-строчный. Всё как [здесь](http://web-standards.ru/articles/vertical-align/). Но результата нет. Что я делаю не так?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CryMap</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#videoBG').on('ended', function () {
                this.load();
                this.play();
            });
        });
    </script>
<script>
    function go(obj) {

        var div = $(obj).find(".link");

        $(div).addClass("link-anim");
    }
    function stop(obj) {

        var div = $(obj).find(".link");

        $(div).removeClass("link-anim");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="backGroundLayer">
        <video autoplay muted id="videoBG">
            <source src="~/Video/BG.webm" type="video/webm" />
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top:20%;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="tile" onmousemove="go(this)" onmouseout="stop(this)">
            <h1 style="color:red;" class="header">CRYMAP #1</h1>
            <p style="color:white;">X5 / KITS / CLANS / INSTACRAFT / STACK / TP</p>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <div class="link">
                    Hello world
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" onmousemove="go(this)" onmouseout="stop(this)">
        <div class="tile">
            <h1 style="color:red;" class="header">CRYMAP #2</h1>
            <p style="color:white;">X10 / KITS / NO-CLANS / INSTACRAFT / STACK / TP</p>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <div class="link">
                    Hello world
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" onmousemove="go(this)" onmouseout="stop(this)">
        <div class="tile">
            <h1 style="color:#00a2ff;" class="header">ГРУППА ВК</h1>
            <p style="color:white;">ТЕХ. ПОДДЕРЖКА / НОВОСТИ / ИНФО. / КОНКУРСЫ</p>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <div class="link">
                    Hello world
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" onmousemove="go(this)" onmouseout="stop(this)">
        <div class="tile">
            <h1 style="color:#bababb;" class="header">ГРУППА <small style="color:#bababb;">steam</small></h1>
            <p style="color:white;">ТЕХ. ПОДДЕРЖКА / НОВОСТИ / ИНФО</p>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <div class="link">
                    Hello world
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#backGroundLayer {
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: no-display;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Code-Pro-Bold';
    src: url(/fonts/Code-Pro-Bold-LC.ttf);
}

.tile {
    font-family: Code-Pro-Bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(52, 59, 67, 0.82);
    min-height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.btn-container {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.link {
    background-color: #21262b;
    color: white;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 22px;
    height: 30px;
}

.link-anim {
    transform: translate(0,-30px);
}

.header {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Как видно со скрина элемент с текстом Hello World должен выровняться по низу. Но этого не происходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.tile {
position: relative;
}
```

Чтобы выстраивать дочерние относительного него

```
.btn-container {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Сам дочерний помещаем снизу

Comment: ваш способ работает без vertical-align - это удивительно! Я удивлён как vertical-align  не работает во всех случаях!

Comment: я если не ошибаюсь это свойство работает только в табличной вёрстке  либо если для div предано через display свойство table-cell либо table-row